NextJS Vercel Application is able to call localhost python webbapplication
So I have a Vercel Deployed Application based on nextjs. I also have another python flask application that i have deployed on vercel. But it is not running on vercel as of now. Only locally...
So since I have not deployed it yet, the request I make is towards localhost:5000/route
even in production.
While I was testing my application in production I was expecting it to fail when i press the button that triggers the request towards localhost:5000. But it doesnt for some reason?
I can see locally in my terminal that I am calling my localhost flask server, from my vercel production application???
I cleared cache, cookies and history. Still the same problem..
Is there something in NextJS i need to do or in vercel that i am missing?
This makes no sense to me.
It should tell me that there is no localhost:5000 server existing.. but it isnt.

I forgot to mention that I did a
client_ip = request.remote_addr to check which IP is calling my from my production vercel. And i am getting localhost (127.0.0.1) for some reason.
